# How to move the Mini Profiler (ms) bubble to the Right Side in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-mini-profiler

I have tried overriding CSS but am not able to move the bubble that shows up on the left to move to the right side. Is there any setting that I can change to achieve this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 3):

You can set configuration options using the configuration accessor on Rack::MiniProfiler. For example:

Rack::MiniProfiler.config.position = 'right'

https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler